# Cancel button HTML jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi I am stuck with my current work because of this cancel button issue.

Here I will explain my problems with some screen shorts
[image]

This is my first page when iam click to the the first radio button[Unique] it goes to this

[image]

Here I want when I click cancel button it goes back to first screen short but when I click it does like dis

[image]
This is ma full code

```
   <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-
 ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 <style>
     .raddiv{
        height: 30px;        
     }
    .sitehtn{
     display: none
            }        

    .container       
     {
    width: 100%;
    height: 600px;
    background-color: rgb(179, 174, 174);        
     }

    #datepickerT
    {
    margin-left: 2em;
    }

    .eventDateDiv
    {
    height: 150px;
    width: 65%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    }
    #daysBetween
    {
    margin-top: -1.4em;
    margin-left: 30%;
    }
    .eventShowDiv
    {
    height: 306px;
     width: 65%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;

    }
    .event{
    color: green;
    margin-top: 5px;}
  </style>
   <script>
          $(function() {
        $( "#datepickerF" ).datepicker({
            showOn: "button",
           buttonImage: "calendar.gif",
          buttonImageOnly: true
        });

   $( "#datepickerT" ).datepicker({
              showOn: "button",
            buttonImageOnly: true
         });
$('#getdays').click(function() {
     var start = $('#datepickerF').datepicker('getDate');
       var end   = $('#datepickerT').datepicker('getDate');
      var days   = (end - start)/1000/60/60/24;
      document.getElementById("daysBetween").innerText=days;

           });

    $(".radioBtn").click(function() {
    $(".textBox").hide();
    if ($(this).attr("id") == "courtierRadio") {
    $("#faderad").fadeOut();
   var is= $("#txt1, #txt2,#txt3,#getmrr,#rmvmrr")
   is.show();

    } else if ($(this).attr("id") == "agenceRadio") {
         $("#fadfirst").fadeOut();
     var vs=$("#txt5,#txt6,#txt7,#txt8").show();
     vs.show();
    }   

    });
       $("#getmrr").click(function() {
      $('#mytable tbody>tr:last').clone(true).insertAfter('#mytable tbody>tr:last');
      return false;

    });
    $("#rmvmrr").click(function() {

      $("#mytable").remove();

      return false;

    });
      function myFunction()
       {
       $("#getmrr").append(is);
        }
      });

      </script>
              </head>
       <body>
     <div class="container">

        <div class="eventDateDiv">
            <div class="event">
                EVENT DATE
            </div>

            <p>FROM: <input type="text" id="datepickerF" /></p>
            <p>To: <input type="text" id="datepickerT" /></p>


            <button id="getdays">NO.OF DAYS </button>
            <p id="daysBetween"> </p>

        </div> 
        <div class="eventShowDiv">
            <div class="event">
                EVENT SHOW TIME
            </div>
            <p>TYPE OF SHOW: </p>
     <div id="fadfirst" class="raddiv">         
               <label>
      <input type="radio" name="sitewebGroup" value="Courtier" id="courtierRadio" 
    class="radioBtn" />Unique
   </label>
      <table id="mytable" width="500" >
   <tbody>
   <tr>
<td>
     <input type="text" name="site" class="sitehtn" id="txt1" />
     <input type="text" name="site" class="sitehtn" id="txt2" />
      <input type="text" name="site" class="sitehtn" id="txt3" />
  </td>
     </tr>
  </tbody>
      </table>
       <button id="getmrr" class="sitehtn" >addmore</button>
       <button id="rmvmrr" class="sitehtn" >Cancel</button>

     <br />
     </div>
   <div id="faderad">
        <label>
      <input type="radio" name="sitewebGroup" value="Agence" id="agenceRadio" 
    class="radioBtn" />
     Varied
    </label>

   <input type="text" name="textfield3" class="sitehtn" />

        <input type="text" name="textfield" class="sitehtn" id="txt5" />   
          <input type="text" name="textfield" class="sitehtn" id="txt6" />  
         <input type="text" name="textfield" class="sitehtn" id="txt7" />   
            <input type="text" name="textfield" class="sitehtn" id="txt8" />             
</div>                  
        </div> 
    </div> 
       </body>
        </html>
```

Iam just newcommer to this so please provide some guiding with your valueble comments

Comment: Select -> Crop Image -> save as ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell the browser to show the "Varied" radio button option and hide the "addmore" and "Cancel" buttons.

Change the click event associated with the cancel button from

```
$("#rmvmrr").click(function() {

   $("#mytable").remove();

   return false;

});
```

to

```
$("#rmvmrr").click(function() {

    $("#mytable").remove();
    $("#faderad").show();
    $("#getmrr").hide();
    $("#rmvmrr").hide();

    return false;

 });
```

Working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/czrTu/2/)

Answer (score 0):

I would think that

```
$("#rmvmrr").click(function() {

      $("#mytable").remove();

      return false;

    });
```

to:

```
$("#rmvmrr").click(function() {

      $("#mytable").hide();

      return false;

    });
```

would do the trick to hide it.

if you want to remove it:
I would say, move the buttons up into the table since they are out of the tag, and say:

```
$("#myTable").html("");
```

Comment: :Thankx for your quick replay i edited my code with yours but it still give me the output that i shown in the third screen short .actually i want that when i click the cancel button it goes to back to the screen short 1..Is it possible

Comment: I think no matter what you need to move the two buttons up a few lines so that they are before the </table> tag. Let me relook at the code so I can get you the checkbox back too!

Comment: Is there a reason you're using tables?

Comment: Also can you show me a screen cap of what should happen if varied is picked?

Comment: no i add table so that when i click add button it adds one more row

Comment: Same as Screen short 2 when varied radio utton clicks